# Login to local db with ip

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I install sqlserver and login with SSMS with windows auth. and server = `DESKTOP-XXXXX\MSSQLSERVER01`

When I tried to connect with 127.0.0.1 ot 127.0.0.1:1433 I can't

I put into TCP/IP

[image] but still I can't login with `127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER01`
why is that?

Comment: Sounds like you need to [enable TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278115/1948808)

Comment: Also, your first example shows a connection to a named instance `MSSQLSERVER01` while the examples with the IP you're omitting the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a SQL server named instance, by defaut, it have to be contacted on a random port not ont the port 1433.

Please use 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER01 or change the tcp/ip configuration and set a fixed port.
Verify that sql server agent is running. This is how a named instance is translated to the right dynamic or static port.

Comment: see my update  please

Comment: Have yu restarted the instance after tcp config? Is the sql server browser started?